# Variable Values changing if one value in changed

Tags: iphone, ipad, variables, uitextfield

I have two variable problem is that they both have defual values on has 12.90 and other has 40 so when i change the variable value 40 to 45 then 12.90 also becomes also 45. I am changing value by textfielddid change event.

[image]

this is image

```
NSLog(@"Clinical Data %.2f",appDelegate.p_ClinInf_Yes_NV_InModel);
NSLog(@"Fatal Data %.2f",appDelegate.p_Fatal_Yes_NV_InModel);


[textFieldOne addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldTextDidChangeOneF:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];


 -(void)textFieldTextDidChangeOneF:(UITextField*)tf{

NSLog(@"Testing Successful Fatal One");


appDelegate.p_Fatal_Yes_NV_InModel  = [[textFieldOne text] floatValue];

appDelegate.p_Fatal_No_NV_InModel=100-appDelegate.p_Fatal_Yes_NV_InModel;
    textFieldTwo.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",appDelegate.p_Fatal_No_NV_InModel];

    NSCharacterSet * set = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789."] invertedSet];
    NSString*string=textFieldOne.text;
    if ([string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:set].location != NSNotFound) {
        UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"Only a  
        number can be entered into this input field " delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"        
       otherButtonTitles:nil];
      [alert show];
      [alert release];
        textFieldOne.text=@"";


    }


    NSLog(@"Fata Data %.2f",appDelegate.p_Fatal_Yes_NV_InModel);

    }
```

I have called differet methods on same button may be due to this values are conflicting.

other method is

```
-(void)textFieldTextDidChangeOneCI:(UITextField*)tf{

NSLog(@"Testing Successful");

appDelegate.p_ClinInf_Yes_NV_InModel  = [[textFieldOne text] floatValue];

appDelegate.p_ClinInf_No_NV_InModel=100-appDelegate.p_ClinInf_Yes_NV_InModel;

textFieldTwo.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",appDelegate.p_ClinInf_No_NV_InModel];

NSCharacterSet * set = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789."] invertedSet];
NSString*string=textFieldOne.text;
if ([string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:set].location != NSNotFound) {
    UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"Only a number can be entered into this input field " delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
            textFieldOne.text=@"";


  }

appDelegate.p_ClinInf_No_NV_InModel=100-appDelegate.p_ClinInf_Yes_NV_InModel;

textFieldTwo.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",appDelegate.p_ClinInf_No_NV_InModel];

NSLog(@"p_ClinInf_No_NV_InModel Text Two Data %.2f",appDelegate.p_ClinInf_No_NV_InModel);

 }
```

View Did load method

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {


appDelegate=[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    popImageView.hidden=YES;
closeButton.hidden=YES;

if([titleName isEqualToString:@"Westnile Disease"])
{
    bgImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"wnd2_bg.png"];
    barImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"eee1.png"];

    barImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"eee1.png"];
    labelFour.text=@"99.57";
    labelOne.text=@"12.90";
    labelTwo.text=@"0.43";
    labelThree.text=@"87.10";
    float valueone;
    valueone = appDelegate.p_ClinInf_Yes_NV_InModel;

    textFieldOne.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",valueone];

        NSLog(@" Working one %.2f",appDelegate.p_ClinInf_Yes_NV_InModel);
        NSLog(@"Working Two %.2f",appDelegate.p_ClinInf_Yes_V_InModel);

        textFieldTwo.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",appDelegate.p_ClinInf_No_NV_InModel];
        textFieldThree.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", appDelegate.p_ClinInf_Yes_V_InModel];
        textFieldFour.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",appDelegate.p_ClinInf_No_V_InModel];
    NSLog(@"Clinical Data %.2f",appDelegate.p_ClinInf_Yes_NV_InModel);
        NSLog(@"Fatal Data %.2f",appDelegate.p_Fatal_Yes_NV_InModel);
       }

if([titleName isEqualToString:@"Eastern Equine Encephalomyelitis"])
 {

    bgImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"eee2_bg.png"];

    barImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"eee1.png"];
    textFieldOne.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",appDelegate.p_ClinInf_Yes_NV_InModel];
    textFieldTwo.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",appDelegate.p_ClinInf_No_NV_InModel];
    textFieldThree.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", appDelegate.p_ClinInf_Yes_V_InModel];
    textFieldFour.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",appDelegate.p_ClinInf_No_V_InModel];

    }

if([titleName isEqualToString:@"Western Equine Encephalomyelitis"])

     {
    bgImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"wee2_bg.png.png"];
    NSLog(@"appDelegate.p_ClinInf_Yes_NV_InModel %.2f",appDelegate.p_ClinInf_Yes_NV_InModel);
    barImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"eee1.png"];

        appDelegate.p_ClinInf_No_NV_InModel=100-appDelegate.p_ClinInf_Yes_NV_InModel;

    appDelegate.p_ClinInf_No_V_InModel=100- appDelegate.p_ClinInf_Yes_V_InModel;
    textFieldOne.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",appDelegate.p_ClinInf_Yes_NV_InModel];
    textFieldTwo.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",appDelegate.p_ClinInf_No_NV_InModel];
    textFieldThree.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", appDelegate.p_ClinInf_Yes_V_InModel];
    textFieldFour.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",appDelegate.p_ClinInf_No_V_InModel];
    }

if([titleName isEqualToString:@"Venezuelan Equine Encephalomyelitis"])  {

    bgImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"page2_bg.png"];

    barImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"eee1.png"];
    textFieldOne.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",appDelegate.p_ClinInf_Yes_NV_InModel];
    textFieldTwo.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",appDelegate.p_ClinInf_No_NV_InModel];
    textFieldThree.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", appDelegate.p_ClinInf_Yes_V_InModel];
    textFieldFour.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",appDelegate.p_ClinInf_No_V_InModel];



    }

  r_Fatal_w_Euthanasia_NV=appDelegate.p_ClinInf_Yes_NV_InModel *     appDelegate.p_Fatal_Yes_NV_InModel * appDelegate.p_Euthanasia_Yes_NV_InModel * 1;
```

r_Fatal_w_Spontaneous_Death_NV=appDelegate.p_ClinInf_Yes_NV_InModel *appDelegate.p_Fatal_Yes_NV_InModel *appDelegate.p_Euthanasia_No_NV_InModel * 1;

```
r_NonFatal_w_Perpetual_Sequelae_NV=appDelegate.p_ClinInf_Yes_NV_InModel *appDelegate.p_Fatal_No_NV_InModel * 1 * appDelegate.p_Sequelae_Yes_NV_InModel;
r_NonFatal_w_Full_Recovery_NV=appDelegate.p_ClinInf_Yes_NV_InModel * appDelegate.p_Fatal_No_NV_InModel * 1 * appDelegate.p_Sequelae_No_NV_InModel;
r_Subtotal_ClinInf_NV=r_Fatal_w_Euthanasia_NV + r_Fatal_w_Spontaneous_Death_NV + r_NonFatal_w_Perpetual_Sequelae_NV + r_NonFatal_w_Full_Recovery_NV;

r_Fatal_w_Euthanasia_V= appDelegate.p_ClinInf_Yes_V_InModel * p_Fatal_Yes_V_InModel * appDelegate.p_Euthanasia_Yes_V_InModel * 1;
r_Fatal_w_Spontaneous_Death_V= appDelegate.p_ClinInf_Yes_V_InModel * appDelegate.p_Fatal_Yes_V_InModel *appDelegate.p_Euthanasia_No_V_InModel * 1;
r_NonFatal_w_Perpetual_Sequelae_V= appDelegate.p_ClinInf_Yes_V_InModel * appDelegate.p_Fatal_No_V_InModel * 1 * appDelegate.p_Sequelae_Yes_V_InModel;
r_NonFatal_w_Full_Recovery_V=appDelegate.p_ClinInf_Yes_V_InModel * appDelegate.p_Fatal_No_V_InModel * 1 * appDelegate.p_Sequelae_No_V_InModel;

r_Subtotal_ClinInf_V=r_Fatal_w_Euthanasia_V + r_Fatal_w_Spontaneous_Death_V + r_NonFatal_w_Perpetual_Sequelae_V + r_NonFatal_w_Full_Recovery_V;

/*********************Unvaccinated horse Graph Values **********/

   r_Fatal_V=r_Fatal_w_Spontaneous_Death_V + r_Fatal_w_Euthanasia_V;



[textFieldOne addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldTextDidChangeOneCI:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
[textFieldThree addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldTextDidChangeThreeCI:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];

[super viewDidLoad];
    }
```

Comment: I beg you pardon, please format/align your code

Comment: 2nd. use camelCaseNamingConvention not underscore_based_naming_convention_in_cocoa;

Comment: @AnoopVaiday thanks i will use camelCaseNamingConvention

Answer (score 0):

Just Comment this bellow line in your `textFieldTextDidChangeOneF` method..

```
textFieldTwo.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",appDelegate.p_ClinInf_No_NV_InModel];
```

**UPDATE:**

First declare `BOOL` variable in your .h file with this name `isTextFieldOne` and then do something like bellow...

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (textField == textFieldOne) {
        isTextFieldOne = True;
    }
    else{
        isTextFieldOne = False;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

and in replace bellow method with your Method...

```
-(void)textFieldTextDidChangeOneF:(UITextField*)tf{

   if (isTextFieldOne){

       NSLog(@"Testing Successful Fatal One");
       appDelegate.p_Fatal_Yes_NV_InModel  = [[textFieldOne text] floatValue];
       appDelegate.p_Fatal_No_NV_InModel=100-appDelegate.p_Fatal_Yes_NV_InModel;
       textFieldTwo.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",appDelegate.p_Fatal_No_NV_InModel];

       NSCharacterSet * set = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789."] invertedSet];
       NSString*string=textFieldOne.text;
       if ([string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:set].location != NSNotFound) {
           UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"Only a  
        number can be entered into this input field " delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"        
       otherButtonTitles:nil];
           [alert show];
           [alert release];
           textFieldOne.text=@"";
       }
       NSLog(@"Fata Data %.2f",appDelegate.p_Fatal_Yes_NV_InModel);
    }
}
```

Comment: no its not like this when we change any thing textfieldone then texitfield2 values changes that is given method not like this

Comment: @AliImran just remove or comment this line dude.. and test it textFieldTwo.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",appDelegate.p_Fatal_No_NV_InModel]; in textFieldTextDidChangeOneF method.. try and let me know...

Comment: ok post the method textFieldShouldEndEditing and textFieldShouldReturn of UItextField delegate method...

Comment: I have also added view did load code so that you may get clear

Comment: - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
 
 
 [textFieldOne resignFirstResponder];
 [textFieldTwo resignFirstResponder];
 [textFieldThree resignFirstResponder];
 [textFieldFour resignFirstResponder];
 
 
 
 
 
 
 return YES;

Comment: @AliImran then something wrong in your delegate method shouldChangeCharactersInRange and 
textFieldShouldEndEditing bcoz you tell me that its change the value of textfieldTwo when i done editing of textfieldOne right??

Comment: yes please see this i have two text boxes ok one two if enter 10 in one second will get 90 automatically so probelm is that when change the value in other metod for text one then it also appears in first

Comment: mean i have two text field and two option CI and FA if CI method is used then value becomes 40textf1 and 60textf2 so when in FA method i change value of textf1 then it CI it also becomes the value of FA

Comment: yes now understand why its happen... bcoz when you change the firsttextfield value at that time textFieldTextDidChangeOneF method call bcoz you set this method when change the value of firsttextbox with its UIControlEventEditingChanged Event so its happen dude..

Comment: then just create one bool value and do something with this otherwise create button and set that method for ChangeEvent of textfieldFirst and set nil at that secondtextfield editing.. just try to understand this logic...

Comment: can you please explain how to do this with BOOL values please

Comment: no dude... wait i create some logic about that and after i will post now i work on my project and test in web-apis so after i do something for that..

Comment: @AliImran see i update answer , get some idea from that logic... :)

Comment: i did not get this can you explain this

Comment: see here what i do , when use click on any textfield the first method called is textFieldShouldBeginEditing delegate method, here i set one BOOL variable if here user tap on firsttextbox then bool variable set as a true and then when user change value of that firsttextbox then called textFieldTextDidChangeOneF method , in this method first check if that variable is true means usertap on first textbox and then system use that code and change the FA code otherwise not changed any value of that variable..